# AudioStreamBasicDescription not being filled, llbd shows it nil, variable inspector doesnt

Tags: swift, xcode, core-audio, lldb

I have this snippet of code

```
        var dataFormat: AudioStreamBasicDescription?
        var propSize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioStreamBasicDescription>.size)
        try SCoreAudioError.check(status: AudioFileGetProperty(audioFileID!, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &propSize, &dataFormat), "Couldn't get file's data format")
```

The variable is somekind being filled, but the llbd debugger shows my variable `dataFormat` value as `nil` (by printing it with `po dataFormat`), while the Variable inspector says that such variable is not `nil` (it is equal to `some` with a content)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

I had to initialize the `AudioStreamBasicDescription`, before passing it as a reference

`var dataFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription.init()`

I had gotten confused because it looks like the pattern of passing an empty optional by reference to then be filled is common with `opaque` types (I think)..